# Is it possible to embed a wheel inside another Python wheel

Tags: python, windows, python-wheel

I want to release a PyPI package that depends on [OpenBabel](https://pypi.org/project/openbabel/). The maintainers of OpenBabel uploaded binary Windows wheels for Python 3.7, but not for later versions of Python. Christoph Gohlke's [excellent site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#_openbabel) contains wheels for versions 3.8 and up, but they are not on PyPI.

I want users of my package to just `pip install my-package` and have openbabel installed as well. If they use Python 3.7 on Windows, openbabel will be loaded from PyPI. If they use a newer version of Python, installing my package will fail, because there's no wheel, and installing openbabel from source on Windows is a real pain.

I want to include the precompiled wheels from Christoph Gohlke's site in my wheel, and install them. Is there any reasonable way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Use `local path dependencies` instead of normal dependencies.

In this case you will need to **embed source code of OpenBabel into your own code** (e.g. as a submodule).

Then you will need to change OpenBabel dependency from a normal one into a local one within your project requirement.

After having OpenBabel embeded into your project, you won't need to change the OpenBabel part, and you can continue dev on your own code.

And your will have OpenBabel in your wheel everytime you package your project.

===== Example =====

As an example, your project structure would be like this:

```bash
YourProject
├── pyproject.toml
├── openbabel_copy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
└── myproject
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── ...
```

In your `pyproject.toml`, you would have lines like this, if your are using `poetry`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
openbabel = { path = "openbabel_copy" }
scipy = "^1.6.3"
protobuf = "^3.17.1"
...
```

So that you would be able to use and import openbabel in your `myproject` without problem.

And this is called `local path dependency`.

However if your are using other packaging tools, I don't know how to do this...(Poetry is fancy and good to use, except for its slow dependency parsing system...but I would still strongly recommend: )

Comment: I don't want to use openbabel's sources (compiling them requires installing many other dependencies), I want to use the openbabel wheel files that are *not* on pypi.

Comment: @zmbq unfortunately i don't think it's possible. You could view a `wheel` as a compiled binary which supports only a specific platform. Since it is compiled, it would not support other platforms. Similarly, a wheel could only support specific python version which defined by itself. For more info about python wheel, see: https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention

Comment: That is not an issue. The Python 3.8 wheel for 64 bit Windows will contain the 3.8 wheel for 64 bit Windows of OpenBabel.

Comment: @zmbq like you said, `If they use a newer version of Python, installing my package will fail, because there's no wheel`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was not an elegant one - I created a new github public repo, and placed the wheels from Christoph Gohlke's site as release artifacts in that repo. I then added an https:// dependency for those wheels, instead of just the `openbabel` package.